# Position of fixed not working in unordered list tag

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my own select option element. But when i try position fixed and apply some css to the li tag then all li lists are not shown. It shows only one list. I tried a lot but couldn't! Please help me! Here's my short code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <style>
        #main-content{
            height: 380px;
            width: 700px;
            background-color: #3498db;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
        span{
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
        a{
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        ul li{
            background-color: #e74c3c;
            padding: 0.3em 5em 0.3em 0.3em;
            cursor: pointer;
            list-style: none;
            position: fixed;

        }
        li:hover{
            background-color: #dadada;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "main-content">
        <div id = "menu">
            <ul id = "menus">
                <span>Select...&nbsp;<a href = "javascript:void(0);" id = "content">></a></span>   
                <li>Sausage</li>
                <li>Burger</li>
                <li>Chicken</li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making the `li` fixed? Remove `position: fixed` and they display as intended.

Comment: Hi FuriousD! I am creating my own custom dropdown menu! I am keeping position fixed so that it doesn't acquire space in div. Suppose theres a text paragraph just below the dropdown in same div! And when i click that it pushes text paragraph downward to show all the lists if i dont keep position fixed! I want to prevent that! But it won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` fixes the position of the element, and in your case it's in `li` element, so all the `li` elements overlaps and you can see only the last `li` element.

Further, to show and hide the list item, you can use `display: none` and `display: block`.

> **Update**(asked in comment): ***Text below the drop down should not move on mouse over drop down element***.

```
#menu{
       position:relative;
    }

ul{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:0;
    top:10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```css
#main-content {
  height: 380px;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  padding:20px;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#menu{
  position:relative;
}

ul{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left:0;
  top:10px;
  padding:0 10px;
}

ul li {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  padding: 0.3em 5em 0.3em 0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  max-width:100px;  
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
}

#menu:hover li {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="menu">
        <span>Select...&nbsp;<a href = "javascript:void(0);" id = "content">></a></span>
    <ul id="menus">
      <li>Sausage</li>
      <li>Burger</li>
      <li>Chicken</li>
    </ul>
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text<br/>
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text<br/>
  </div>
  Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text<br/>
  Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: But i don't want it to acquire space around a div! Like when i insert text just below the dropdown then it pushes text downward!

Comment: I don't get you, can you please explain more? Where you don't want to acquire space? for which div you have talked about?

Comment: Suppose theres a dropdown menu you just created, right and theres some text just below it in the same div! Then when i hover over dropdown menu it pushes text downward! I want to prevent that!

Comment: That's it! Thank you!